# How do I calculate avg and count on multiple columns involving many tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here are my different tables:

```
computers (id,name)
monitors (id,name)
computer_monitor (id, computer_id,monitor_id)
useractivity (id,userid,timestamp,computer_monitor_id,ip)
useropinion (id,userid,computer_monitor_id,timestamp,rating)
user (id,name,email)
```

I want to search after the name of computer or monitor and get a row like this in return:

```
computer name and/or monitor name
computer_monitor_id
avg(rate)
count(useractivity)
```

avg(rate) is on that specific `computer_monitor_id` that matches the name, the same goes for count.

A computer with no connection to monitor has a value of 0 on monitor field in computer_monitor table and vice versa for `monitor->computer`.

useractivity and useropinion only contains the ID from computer_monitor table

Comment: @Siva, I reintroduced the OP's *and/or* wording in desired output.  (Normally I understand "foo/bar" to mean "foo (exclusive) or bar".)

Comment: By `avg(rate)` you meant `avg(rating)`, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the query should be built around the `computer_monitor` table. All other tables connect to it, including those from which you want to obtain the stats.

```sql
SELECT
  c.name AS ComputerName,
  m.name AS MonitorName,
  uo.AverageRating,
  ua.ActivityCount
FROM computer_monitor cm
  LEFT JOIN computer c ON c.id = cm.computer
  LEFT JOIN monitor  m ON m.id = cm.monitor

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT computer_monitor_id, AVG(rating) AS AverageRating
    FROM useropinion
    GROUP BY computer_monitor_id
  ) uo ON cm.id = uo.computer_monitor_id

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT computer_monitor_id, COUNT(*) AS ActivityCount
    FROM useractivity
    GROUP BY computer_monitor_id
  ) ua ON cm.id = ua.computer_monitor_id
```

Actually, as you can see, `useropinion` and `useractivity` are aggregated first, *then* joined. This is to avoid the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) effect when a `computer_monitor.id` matches more than one row both in `useropinion` and in `useractivity`.

Comment: ok, Super SWEET, altmost there. But how if I would like to see those with no useractivity also ?? So that activity count becomes zero. In the case that I have useractivity with only a couple of rows, and computers>1000, I want to be able to search on everyone.

Comment: @TimTimTim: You can always replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN, if I'm not misunderstanding you. Accordingly, replace `ua.ActivityCount` in the select list with `COALESCE(ua.ActivityCount) AS ActivityCount` if you want to see 0s instead of NULLs.

Comment: Jeah, thank you! the only thing i'm missing now is search on both c.name and m.name. One or the other works, but not both--> where c.name LIKE '%$name%' = works, but I want the result from both c.name and m.name? Any Idea?

Comment: Any Idea how I could add a computer_monitor_id to one row, and from a new table comment(id,timestamp,userid,computer_monitor), add a row for newest timestamp. Pluss add row for count of rating as a the last.

Comment: @TimTimTim: 1) Re: add `computer_monitor_id` – not sure I've understood you, perhaps you just need to include something like `uo.computer_monitor_id` or `ua.computer_monitor_id` in the select list. 2) Re: add latest row from `comment` – search SO for questions tagged as [`greatest-n-per-group` + `mysql`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql), that should get you started, I think. If you are still struggling, please ask a *new* question about how to combine retrieving last comments with whatever query you end up by that moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394226/adding-new-rows-for-search-purposes-where-exsisting-inner-joins-are-implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$res_comp = mysql_query("select * from computers where name = '$name'");
$res_monitor = mysql_query("select * from monitor where name = '$name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($res_comp) > 0)
{
$row_comp = mysql_fetch_array($res_comp);
$comp_id = $row_comp['id'];
$res_result = mysql_query("select computers.name, computer_monitor.id, count(computer_monitor_id) from computers, computer_monitor, useractivity where computers.id = '$comp_id' AND computer_monitor_id = '$comp_id' AND useractivity.computer_monitor_id = '$comp_id'");

}
// repeat the same for monitor also. then use mysql_fetch_array to show your data.
?>
```

hopefully this will help.

Comment: || bo_computers.id = '$comp_id' AND computer_monitor_id = '$comp_id'  || bo.computer.id and computer_monitor_id is not the same ID. computer_monitor_id is the ID to the connection beetween monitor_id and computer_id

Answer (score 0):

This *might* do the trick...(one table with the computer/monitor relation ship, the other with a xref table threw me, and check the join types depending on your data)

```
SELECT computers.name AS ComputerName
    , monitors.name AS MonitorName
    , AVG(useropinion.rating) AS AvgRating
    , COUNT(useractivity.id) AS ActivityCount
FROM computers
INNER JOIN computer_monitor ON (computers.id = computer_monitor.computer_id)
INNER JOIN useractivity ON (computers.id = useractivity.computer_id)
INNER JOIN monitors ON (computer_monitor.monitor_id = monitors.id)
INNER JOIN useropinion ON (computer_monitor.id = useropinion.computer_monitor_id) AND (monitors.id = useractivity.monitor_id)
INNER JOIN USER ON (useropinion.user_id = user.id) AND (useractivity.user_id = user.id)
```

Comment: AND monitors.id = useractivity.monitor_id,  I dont have monitor_id in useractivity only the connction ID. I wonder if I should use (computer_monitor.id = useractivity.computer_montior_id) instead??